# Excel / Google Sheet track cell value over time?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Excuse me if this is very basic but beyond real-time data integration in excel I'm an absolute novice,
In [this google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OW84XMTdSx4-dwkUB6VGSgjSdi_Ty4oKKAide7UZWt0/edit?usp=sharing) I'm trying to create a function to track cell contents over time, for example, allow the contents of cell F32 to change and then each month (at the press of a button or some such other trigger) paste the new value into another cell (Starting at AU10 for instance and going down one row each month) to track the change in cell value over time.

I've released the spreadsheet in a few finance subreddits and so far the most requested feature is tracking net worth / adherence to the budget over time but I can't for the life of me figure out how to integrate that functionality. Any response would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Decide which you will use as they both use different macro languages. Excel is vba and googlesheets is java iirc.

Comment: Great tip, I'm using Sheets currently and just put excel in the title because I believed them interchangeable and thought the excel savvy among us may be able to help. Thanks for the tip, always good to learn new things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addressing the **Google Sheets** aspect of the question...

To *automatically* maintain a permanent record of a cell value that changes over time, you will need a script that runs on a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).

The same can be done with a [macro](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7665004) that runs when the user presses a shortcut key.

See the [appendValuesToArchiveSheet](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/27095918?msgid=27163801) script for sample code of how to let your users track how their net worth changes over time. You can collect the values to track into a contiguous range somewhere in the spreadsheet and archive them all as one row periodically.

To archive multiple rows the same way, while maintaining row structure, use the [appendRowsToArchiveSheet](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/41717054?msgid=43025271) script.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I should have clarified, I don't need the data to populate automatically each month, the sheet would need to be manually filled out each month and I would Just like a shortcut to move the data from the amended calculations each month to a new entry in a separate table.

The Archivesheet function looks promising, I'll have a deeper look through it and see if I can understand how to make it function the way I want, from my understanding I should collate the data I want to archive in a single row and use that function to paste it??

Many thanks for the response :)

Comment: I think your question is clear enough. Will edit the answer to add another option.

Comment: At a glance that edit seems to do exactly what I'm looking for, 
You sir are an absolute legend.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome. It seems that since the time you've posted your response some things have changed. In your "appendValuesToArchiveSheet script", where you wrote "choose Tools > Script editor > Blank (this opens a new tab in the browser)", I had to follow the route "Extensions > Apps Script" and the trigger is now a simple option on the left.